# Equivalent ksdensity MATLAB function in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, kernel-density

Is there an equivalent for the following MATLAB code in Python?

I searched for it but I cannot find an equivalent code that provides "Support" and "Function" options in the Python code.

MATLAB code:

```matlab
[f,xi] = ksdensity(data,'Support','positive','Function','cdf');
```

Comment: It has edited now.

Comment: Can you please describe what this code is supposed to do, for those who don't know Matlab?

Comment: It's going to calculate the cumulative distribution function (cdf) by applying log(data) as the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a little different than matlab, but if you install scikit-learn, then you have available following stuff:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html